# Directx - Matrix translation in local axis

Tags: c++, math, matrix, directx

I have difficulty for using matrices

I can move an object, rotate, and move in word coordinate like these:

> matScale* matRotate * matTranslate

But I don't know how to move an object in his local axis
i.e: after rotate, move(0,0,10) i local Z of the object

EDIT:
Sorry but I'm lost :(

I have tried this:

```
D3DXMatrixRotationX(&matRotateX, modell->getPitch());
    D3DXMatrixRotationY(&matRotateY, modell->getYaw());
    D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&matRotateZ, modell->getRoll());

    matRotate = matRotateX * matRotateY * matRotateZ; 




    D3DXMatrixScaling(&matScale, modell->getScale().x, modell->getScale().y, modell->getScale().z);



        Matrix WVP;
        WVP = matScale* matTranslate * matRotate * matView * matProjection;

        Matrix translation;
        D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation, 10, 10, 0); // just for test


        cBuffer.Final = translation * WVP;
```

...but the rotation is around WORLD axis, not local :(

---

EDIT 2:

OK, I begin to understand… we can now:

-Translate my object in local axis with:

translation * matRotate * matScale * matTranslate * matView * matProjection

“or” we can:

-Rotate this object on local axis with:

matRotate * translation * matScale * matTranslate * matView * matProjection

But, I want to do the two transformation in same time ^^, I want to translate in `<local>` AND I want to rotate in `<local>` with the same operation

How it’s possible? :-)

---

EDIT 3

Okay, I think we can simplify that...

I want to move on Z axis of the object, I can do that:

```
if (input.keyPressed(VK_UP))
{
    ship->translate(0, 0, -0.01, ASF3D::LOCAL);

}
```

Then, I update positions of my objects in their class: (fuction: translate)

```
position.x += z * sin(yaw);
position.y += z * sin(pitch);
position.z += z * -cos(yaw);
```

After this, I make my matPosition (Instead of managing a location matrix and a matrix tranlation)

Then, I do my: cBuffer.Final = matScale* matRotate * matTranslate* matView * matProjection;

I can't test atm, but I'm sure it's working and it easier
I'm just not sure about the calculations of trigonometry :P

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far and what exactly does not work

Comment: You are missing a `cos(pitch)` somewhere, i think in both x and z (in order to keep the length of your vector), but besides that this should be a working solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:**
This answer is not specific to DirectX, its about general matrix multiplication. But since you didn`t provide any code or any more information about how you tried to solve the problem, it's the best i can come up with. And it should get you on the right track how transformations with matrices are done.

---

First some general relations of matrices:

```
M*N != N*M  //non-commutative
M*(N*O) = (M*N)*O  //associative
inverse(M*N) = inverse(N)*inverse(N)
```

---

Let `S` be the scaling matrix, `R`the rotation and `T` the translation. Further `x` are the coordinates in local, untransformed coordinates while `w` are the coordinates in world coordinates.

If you multiply coordinates as column-vector from the right, you get something like:

```
w = S*R*T * x  <-> w = S*(R*(T*x))
```

which first translates in the local coordinates of x, then rotates in the translated coordinates, then scales in the translated and rotated coordinates. A transformation `L` in the local coordinate-system can be easily achieved by multiplying 'L' from the right to your current transformation matrix:

```
w = S*R*T * L * x  <-> w = S*(R*(T*(L*x)))
```

if you are fixed to multiply it to the left, you need to transform it first with some matrix `M` and its inverse `I=inverse(M)` like this:

```
w = M*L*I * S*R*T * x
```

one can easily see, that with `M=(S*R*T)` this becomes:

```
w = (S*R*T) * L * inverse(S*R*T) * (S*R*T) * x
w = S*R*T * L * x
```

which is the same as above.

---

If you multiply your coordinates `x` as a row-vector from the left, the above formulas become:

```
w = x * S*R*T <-> w = ((x*S)*R)*T
```

which first scales in the local coordinates of x, then rotates in the scaled coordinates, then translates in the scaled and rotated coordinates.
(...)

```
w = x * L * S*R*T  <-> w = (((x*L)*S)*R)*T
```

(...)

```
w = x * S*R*T * I*L*M
w = x * (S*R*T) * inverse(S*R*T) * L * (S*R*T)
w = x * L * S*R*T
```

**Edit** after you provided some code:

Your `cBuffer.Final` is computed as:

```
cBuffer.Final = translation * WVP;
```

or

```
cBuffer.Final = translation * matScale* matTranslate * matRotate * matView * matProjection;
```

Since DirectX uses row-vectors, this takes your coordinates `x` and then first applies `translation`, moving the object out of the center. Then it applies `matScale` scaling the Object around the center of your coordinate-system (and therefore moving it even further). Then it applies `matTranslate` moving it again. Then it applies `matRotate`, rotating it around the center of your coordinate system (this will move the object in a wide arc, since your object is not centered anymore). Then it applies the `matView` and finally `matProjection` to get the screen-coordinates of your object.

If you want to rotate the object around its local coordinate system, try this:

```
cBuffer.Final = matRotate * translation * matScale * matTranslate * matView * matProjection;
```

This will first rotate the object (while it is still in the center of your coordinate system) and then apply (in order) the `translation`, `matScale`, `matTranslate`, `matView` and `matProjection`.

If you (as stated in the part of your question before the edit) want to move your object in local coordinates along the vector (0,0,10), try this:

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation, 0, 0, 10);
cBuffer.Final = translation * matRotate * matScale * matTranslate * matView * matProjection;
```

**The importan part to note is: The order of your matrix-multiplications determines the order in which transformations are applied. I.e. `A*B != B*A`**

**Edit2:**
To take the example with the spaceship from comment:

Let's say your spaceship has a position and a rotation given by 2 matrices `matPosition` and `matRotate`. Then the final transformation matrix is given by:

```
cBuffer.Final = matScale * matRotate * matPosition * matView * matProjection
```

(See again [this image](http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tmpD72_thumb2_thumb.jpg) why we first rotate and then translate.)

Then if you want to update your `matPosition` by moving the position 5 steps in z-direction you would write:

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation, 0, 0, 5);
matPosition *= translation;
```

But you want to move it in the local z-direction. So what you want to do is to have this transformation:

```
cBuffer.Final = matScale * translation * matRotate * matPosition * matView * matProjection
```

Which (look at the picture again) will first translate, then rotate (giving a translation in local axis) and then move the object to its position. However we anyhow need to "move" this translation into the position-matrix or in the next step it will use the new rotation matrix, which we dont want. But we can rewrite the line as (without scale, view and project):

```
cBuffer.Final = translation * matRotate * matPosition

                /  This is the unity-matrix \ 
cBuffer.Final = matRotate * inverse(matRotate) * translation * matRotate * matPosition 
                            \ - - store this in a new position-matrix - - - - - - - /
cBuffer.Final = matRotate * matNewPosition
```

This leads us to:

```
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&translation, 0, 0, 5);
matPosition = inverse(matRotate) * translation * matRotate * matPosition;
cBuffer.Final = matScale * matRotate * matPosition * matView * matProjection;
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, the important part to note is that the order of your matrices matters. Since you have full access to the matrix multiplications, the part of my original answer using `inverse(S*R*T)` is not relevant to you.

Comment: @Asphodeuls: Look e.g. at [this image](http://what-when-how.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/tmpD72_thumb2_thumb.jpg) (not sure about copyright, so i only link it here). Which one do you want? I guess it's the second, because it behaves the same was as if you had rotated first and then translated in the local coordinate system. I'm not aware of a third possibility.....

Comment: Take for example a spaceship which moves at speed of 5 unit per frames

 

I want to control his orientation with mouse (around his local coordinate system) for pitch, yaw, roll, and at the same time, keep a translation in his local Z (Vector3(0,0,5) )

Comment: I've added an example for that as well. However matrix-multiplications are complex and i understand you need to wrap your head around it for a while. But you should still try to learn a bit how they work and what they do. If trying fails, take a pen and a paper, write down the equations you need or draw what would happen.

Comment: Precisely this is what I did, so I just edit my post to show you what I propose :-) (I just doubt with trigonometry)

Comment: The last formula with inverseRotaton doesn't work but I have found the error in my formula...in fact, it must be: position.x += -z *  cos(pitch)*sin(yaw);             
  position.y += z * sin(pitch);             
  position.z += -z * cos(pitch) * cos(yaw);

Comment: Thanks a lot Anedar! You allowed me to better understand matrix, I'm grateful :) :)